# More semantic html 5 code with bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my (wordpress) bootstrap 3 template more html 5-semantic. Now i wonder if i should use the new html 5 tags for layouting like:

```
<section class="container">
    <article class="row">
        <main class="col-md-8>
            <header><h1>HEADLINE</h1></header>
            ...
        </main>
        <aside class="col-md-4>
            ...
        </aside>
    </article>
</section>
```

or only to divide the document into meaningful parts like:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <article>
                <div class="col-md-8>
                    <main>
                        <div class="col-md-8>
                            <header><h1>HEADLINE</h1></header>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <aside>
                        <div class="col-md-4>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tend to like the second option more because i think it's easier to code and read for complex websites but i tend to code with less tags as possible, too ... . what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

`section` should not contain the main element semantically. But `main` element can contain any. So, you may do as followings:

```
<main>
   <article>
   </article>
   <section>
      <article>you can nest article in section</article>
   </section>
   <section>
   </section>
</main>
<aside>
element aside main element
</aside>
```

While using [`section`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) consider the following points:

- If it makes sense to separately syndicate the content of a `section`
  element, use an `article` element instead.
- Do not use the `section` element as a generic container; this is what
  `div` is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling
  purposes. A rule of thumb is that a `section` should logically appear
  in the outline of a document.

So, consider the following while using [`main`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main):

- `main` must not be a descendant of an `article`, `aside`, `footer`,  `header`,
  or `nav` element.

To consider what should I do or what should I not do you may search in Google like this:

> mdn article html

So, this would result Mozilla developer network's [article](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+article+html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

So, searching is easy like `mdn aside html`, then you would get article of what you need exactly.